# Type-safe JSON deserialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, type-safety

In a Python (3.6) application I receive messages from Kafka in JSON format. (The code base makes heavy use of [static type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and every file is automatically checked using `mypy --strict` to catch type errors as early as possible.)

So I try to deserialize the received messages into objects immediately in order to avoid working with `Dict[str, Any]` instances in the downstream code. I'd like the deserialization to be type-safe, i.e., to not only fail if not all class members are defined in the JSON string, but also if one or more of them have an incorrect type.

My current approach looks as follows:

(The class `Foo` in the unit tests is an example of a typical `target_class`.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Type-safe JSON deserialization
"""

import inspect
from typing import Any, List
import json
import unittest


def get_all_member_variable_names(target_class: Any) -> List[str]:
    """Return list of all public member variables."""
    all_members = [name for name, _ in inspect.getmembers(target_class,\
                       lambda a: not inspect.isroutine(a))]
    return list(filter(lambda name: not name.startswith("__"), all_members))


def deserialize_json(target_class: Any, object_repr: str) -> Any:
    """Constructs an object in a type-safe way from a JSON strings"""
    data = json.loads(object_repr)
    members = get_all_member_variable_names(target_class)
    for needed_key in members:
        if needed_key not in data:
            raise ValueError(f'Key {needed_key} is missing.')
    dummy = target_class()
    for needed_key in members:
        json_type = type(data[needed_key])
        target_type = type(getattr(dummy, needed_key))
        if json_type != target_type:
            raise TypeError(f'Key {needed_key} has incorrect type. '
                            '({json_type} instead of {target_type}')
    return target_class(**data)


class Foo():
    """Some dummy class"""
    val: int = 0
    msg: str = ''
    frac: float = 0.0

    def __init__(self, val: int = 0, msg: str = '', frac: float = 0.0) -> None:
        self.val: int = val
        self.msg: str = msg
        self.frac: float = frac


class TestDeserialization(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test with valid and invalid JSON strings"""

    def test_ok(self) -> None:
        """Valid JSON string"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": 3.14}'
        a_foo: Foo = deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.val, 42)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.msg, 'hello')
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.frac, 3.14)

    def test_missing(self) -> None:
        """Invalid JSON string: missing a field"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello"}'
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)

    def test_incorrect_type(self) -> None:
        """Invalid JSON string: incorrect type of a field"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": "incorrect"}'
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)
```

It works and the unit tests succeed, but I'm not sure if I am missing some potential problem or other opportunities to improve this. It would be cool if you could give me some hints or general criticism.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger The class `Foo` used in the test cases is such an example.

Comment: [Too bad you are not using Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622643/5069029) ;)

Comment: Yes, Data classes, I know. ;) It has to do with TensorFlow compatibility. Soon I'll switch to Python 3.7. But I guess the JSON problem will be the same, except less boilerplate in the definition of the target classes.

Comment: It was more about the behaviour of `typing` in Python 3.6 which, IMHO, is less predictible than in Python 3.7. The decorator at the end of the answer could be updated to work with `typing` 3.6 but would be much verbose, I feel.

Comment: However, I’m a bit disturbed by your unittest. Why would a class with default values for all its arguments raise a `ValueError` if one is missing from a call with `**kwargs`?

Comment: You are right, that is a bit ugly. Ideally I'd like to have not default values at all. However I did not get `get_all_member_variable_names` to work correctly without them. I'd be very happy if you know a better solution.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher: OK, thanks for the correction and sorry for the mistake. I'll move the improved code to a self-answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Get the annotated signature of a `target_class`' `__init__` method;
2. Apply whatever arguments come from the provided JSON string;
3. Check that all arguments are present;
4. Check that all arguments conform to the annotations of the class' `__init__`.

All except the last step is pretty straightforward using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import json
import inspect
from typing import Callable, Any, T


def deserialize_json(target_class: Callable[[Any], T], object_repr: str) -> T:
    data = json.loads(object_repr)
    signature = inspect.signature(target_class)
    bound_signature = signature.bind(**data)
    bound_signature.apply_defaults()
    return target_class(**bound_signature.arguments)
```

[`inspect.Signature.bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind) validate arguments pretty much the same as a real call to `target_class.__init__` would; raising `TypeError` if a positionnal argument is missing or if an extra keyword argument is found.

Now you "just" need to validate the type of the arguments based on the annotations. A simple but potentially sufficient way of doing would check the [`annotation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter.annotation) attribute of each parameter of the `Signature` and check it is the right type using `isinstance`:

```
def deserialize_json(target_class: Callable[[Any], T], object_repr: str) -> T:
    data = json.loads(object_repr)
    signature = inspect.signature(target_class)
    bound_signature = signature.bind(**data)
    bound_signature.apply_defaults()

    for name, value in bound_signature.arguments.items():
        expected_type = signature.parameters[name].annotation
        if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
            raise TypeError('<error message>')

    return target_class(**bound_signature.arguments)
```

Note that this simple example would most likely have [troubles validating Generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49171189/5069029) or [parametrized Generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48572831/5069029). Adapting the code to fit those needs is left as an exercise for the reader (but [Python 3.7 have better support for such checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50563546/5069029)).

---

As a side note, if all target classes ressemble the `Foo` example, and you don't mind having them immutable, you can make use of [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
class Foo(typing.NamedTuple):
    val: int
    msg: str
    frac: float = 1.0


print(Foo(1, 'bar'))  # Foo(val=1, msg='bar', frac=1.0)
print(Foo(2, 'baz', 0.0))  # Foo(val=2, msg='baz', frac=0.0)
print(Foo(3))  # TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

or switch to Python 3.7 and use full-blown [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. This is much better, since I don't need the default values for the class. Using the signature of the target-class constructor is very clever. :) I only had to make some adjustments for `mypy --strict` and `pylint` (see edit of my original post).

Comment: @TobiasHermann As regard to this edit: avoid using `type` and prefer `isinstance`. Not that it matter much for JSON types, but think that `list != typing.List` but `isinstance([], typing.List)` is true.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I [fixed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200445/21464) this too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [help of Mathias Ettinger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200418/21464), here is the improved version:

(I only had to make some additional minor adjustments for `mypy --strict`.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Type-safe JSON deserialization
"""

import inspect
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, TypeVar
import json
import unittest


TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')


def deserialize_dict(target_class: Callable[..., TypeT], data: Dict[str, Any]) -> TypeT:
    """Constructs an object in a type-safe way from a dictionary"""
    signature = inspect.signature(target_class)
    bound_signature = signature.bind(**data)
    bound_signature.apply_defaults()

    for name, _ in bound_signature.arguments.items():
        expected_type = signature.parameters[name].annotation
        if not isinstance(data[name], expected_type):
            json_type = type(data[name])
            raise TypeError(f'Key {name} has incorrect type. '
                            f'{json_type.__name__} instead of '
                            f'{expected_type.__name__}')
    return target_class(**bound_signature.arguments)


def deserialize_json(target_class: Callable[..., TypeT], object_repr: str) -> TypeT:
    """Constructs an object in a type-safe way from a JSON strings"""
    return deserialize_dict(target_class, json.loads(object_repr))


class Foo():
    """Some dummy class"""
    def __init__(self, val: int, msg: str, frac: float) -> None:
        self.val: int = val
        self.msg: str = msg
        self.frac: float = frac


class TestDeserialization(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test with valid and invalid JSON strings"""

    def test_dict(self) -> None:
        """Valid data dict"""
        data = {"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": 3.14}
        a_foo: Foo = deserialize_dict(Foo, data)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.val, 42)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.msg, 'hello')
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.frac, 3.14)

    def test_ok(self) -> None:
        """Valid JSON string"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": 3.14}'
        a_foo: Foo = deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.val, 42)
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.msg, 'hello')
        self.assertEqual(a_foo.frac, 3.14)

    def test_additional(self) -> None:
        """Valid JSON string with an additional field"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": 3.14, "ignore": 1}'
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)

    def test_missing(self) -> None:
        """Invalid JSON string: missing a field"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello"}'
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)

    def test_incorrect_type(self) -> None:
        """Invalid JSON string: incorrect type of a field"""
        object_repr = '{"val": 42, "msg": "hello", "frac": "incorrect"}'
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            deserialize_json(Foo, object_repr)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `deserialize_*` functions annotations return `TypeT`? Or is it a limitation of `mypy`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Of course you are absolutely right again. This was a leftover from my original attempt. I just fixed it.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: Just in case you are interested in hearing this: The idea continued to grow and I made [a library](https://github.com/Dobiasd/undictify) out of it. So thank you again for your help. :)